# How to evaluate the finite power tower $\tan(1°)^{\tan(2°)^{\tan(3°)^{\cdot^{\cdot^{\cdot^{\tan(44°)^{\tan(45°)}}}}}}}$

Tags: trigonometry, tetration, power-towers

Consider the following finite power tower:

$$\Large \tan(1°)^{\tan(2°)^{\tan(3°)^{\cdot^{\cdot^{\cdot^{\tan(44°)^{\tan(45°)}}}}}}}$$

I'm wondering if there is a way to solve this that doesn't rely on brute force (i.e. simply typing the entire power tower out). As, I see it, there are two possibilities:

1. There's some magic trig identity that simplifies this to a small closed form.  I haven't found any such yet.
2. I need to develop some sort of approximation scheme for a computer.

Is (1) possible?  If not, how do I do (2)?

Edit: For clarification, I have manually typed out the problem inside Desmos and arrived at the following answer: [image]

I'd just like to know if this answer is correct, and if so, how I would go about finding an easier way to achieve this answer (whether that be by using a trig identity or some form of computerization, I don't mind) without having the type out every step like I've done above. Thank you,

Comment: Why do people keep downvoting? What's wrong with the question? Why not provide constructive criticism instead of being actively malicious?

Comment: You've given no real reason why you can't use a computer to approximate this, though it is obviously going to be very tiny. Furthermore, the question cannot be generalized, as you'll be raising to the power of infinity at 90 degrees, so I think it would be easier to write a for loop that can do this. It doesn't look like it would provide insight into other problems.

Comment: @SwanKlein Sorry if I may have been unclear in the original post, but my intention was for the power tower to finish at $\tan(45°)$. Also, how would I go about getting a computer to approximate this question? I can't seem to find anything online which could help with setting up a recursion of an exponent increasing in the same way my question does.

Comment: You can omit the last entry since it is $1$ , but apart from that there is no shortcut. Best is to calculate the power tower iteratively. I do not expect a nice closed form.

Comment: @AussieMathematician: I've edited your question to make it a little more answerable.  Please check that it conforms with your intent.

Comment: If it does, please edit into the post what sorts of trig identities you know for $\tan$, so we can explain why you are unlikely to see a simplification.

Comment: Throw the command `N[Nest[{Tan[#[[2]]/180*Pi]^#[[1]],#[[2]]-1} &, {1,44},44],50]` to [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=N%5BNest%5B%7BTan%5B%23%5B%5B2%5D%5D%2F180*Pi%5D%5E%23%5B%5B1%5D%5D%2C%23%5B%5B2%5D%5D-1%7D+%26%2C+%7B1%2C44%7D%2C44%5D%2C50%5D), the number is numerically around `0.2774023141038327352949884041560599701921947221780` (maxima also give the same number under 200 decimal places precison)

Answer (score 2):

Taking them five at the time, the results are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
\text{from} & \text{to} & \text{value} \\
 1 & 5  & 0.0535625370657532607362393 \\
 1 & 10 & 0.4575153711252385756282372 \\
 1 & 15 & 0.2482699982569751321101037 \\
 1 & 20 & 0.2797539387187735772940906 \\
 1 & 25 & 0.2773295827116058036618656 \\
 1 & 30 & 0.2774030591794901804478588 \\
 1 & 35 & 0.2774023124430804526117091 \\
 1 & 40 & 0.2774023141041003428422647 \\
 1 & 45 & 0.2774023141038327352949884
\end{array}
\right)$$

For the fun of it, with an absolute error of $5.79\times 10^{-21}$, the final value is almost
$$\Bigg[e^{-42-\frac{34}{e}-47 e+\frac{7}{\pi }+30 \pi }\,\, \pi ^{23 e-15} \,\,\tan ^{31}(e \pi )\,\,  \sec ^{13}(e \pi )   \Bigg]^{\frac 1 {15}}$$ given by a friend who enjoys this kind of problems.